# Where do I find realURLs replace patterns?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, realurl

Where do I find realURLs replace patterns?
For example realurl replaces a space " " with a line "-". Or "ä" to "ae". And so on. I need the hole "replace-list"

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in `typo3conf/ext/realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php`

Comment: I found this class, but it's late here and I stop for today. I didn't find a fast way to create a list with all rewrites (that's what I need). For the task right now i found a work around, so it's not very important anymore.